# How to fix my shadow catcher?

Tags: shadows, shadowcatcher

What do you suggest I do to fix my shadow catcher plane so that the barrel of the tunnel doesn't leave a gap, causing it to cast a harder shadow?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your Q ... end of your tunnel is hanging over ground? ... so move the edge of shadow plane to forward on level of end tunnel? ... I think I'm missing something, right? If none here please add more details. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. Basically, yes. But if I move the edge, then I lose the shadow of the concrete frame. What I wanted to do is keep the frame as is and modify the plane right below the tunnel so that it adheres just like the other elements.

Comment: You answered your Q now, right?